# how to change the os ubuntu 14.04 to windows completely?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

when i try to install windows 8.1 o.s to my laptop.it shows that the required cannot be selected showing something like drive 0 cannot be installed.i my Ubuntu o.s is in u.e.f.i mode.and the entire o.s is in a single partition which is under the owner of root..i cannot unmount the drive.

Comment: goto http://superuser.com we love ubuntu and want ubuntu to replace windows not vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to convert your hard disk from UEFI to MBR format. You can follow the below steps:

1. Boot in the Windows installation using DVD or USB.
2. From inside Windows Setup, press **Shift+F10** to open a command prompt window or you can go to
   **Repair your computer >> Advanced Options >> Command Prompt**
3. In Command Prompt, open the diskpart tool:

> diskpart

4. Identify the drive to reformat:

> list disk

5. Select the drive, and reformat it:

> select disk "disk number"
>
> clean
>
> convert mbr
>
> exit

Continue with your Windows 8.1 installation. Your problem should be solved by this.

Alternatively you can also convert your UEFI/GPT harddisk from ubuntu and then install Windows 8.1. Have a walk through [GPT/UEFI to MBR conversion](http://www.firewing1.com/blog/2012/03/05/how-convert-gpt-disk-layout-ms-dosmbr-layout-without-data-loss-and-gigabyte-hybrid)

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted whenever it helped (most) in solving the problem.