# If I uninstall windows 10 from my laptop to install Ubuntu will I beable to go back to windows 10 at a later time

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I have an ASUS X555LAB it came with Windows 10 installed but did not come with any windows disk. I want to know if I completely wipe my HDD and install Ubuntu will I be able re-install windows 10 at a later date if I wanted to...

Or should I shrink down my windows partition as much as possible and dual boot. I have never been a big fan of dual booting but I want to make sure I dont lose lose windows 10 forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second option is probably the best because as you said

> Windows 10 installed but did not come with any windows disk

meaning that if you completely reinstall you will lose it

Comment: I guess not if you keep your product key. It's possible to download Windows 10 & burn our usb key of it.

Answer (score 1):

Did ASUS install Windows 10 on your machine as default Operating System?
Or did you buy Win 10 in the Windows Store or get it as (free) upgrade from Win 7+?

In the first case, you should have the product key around somewhere. Probably on a sticker on the device. You can re-activate the Windows installation with that key, in the same fashion as an older Windows edition would be activated.

In the latter case (and some more, see Source link below), Microsoft has given you a Digital Entitlement, and will automatically activate during the installation process

> Digital entitlement is a new method of activation in Windows 10 that doesn't require you to enter a product key.

So, if you have the Product Key or have a Digital Entitlement, you can safely perform a clean install on the full HDD without losing the possibility to return to the previously activated Windows version.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/activation-in-windows-10

Windows Media Creation Tool (needs Windows OS): https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

In order to go back to Windows installation I would recommend to back it up using Clonezilla or from Windows use third party tool called Macrium Reflect. Using the backup you can go back any time you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Go for the resizing and dual boot. Whenever you are comfortable with Ubuntu later, you can reinstall and go for it all the way.
That's how I went. Started dual boot 2 year's ago on a W7, but when W10 came, and U14.04, I wiped the drive. Now looking to go to U16.04 soon.

Answer (score 0):

1. As explained by others, dual boot will be a better option for you compared to   completely wiping out your HDD. You will get best of both worlds. 
   If you are considering this option, do not disturb your C drive(Windows 10 installation). Instead delete any other secondary drive for Ubuntu installation.
2. Also as you don't have any installation disk provided with Windows 10, cleaning HDD might get you in trouble while re-installation. Though having Product Key might be helpful. Still if you prefer to go by this option and want to revert back to Windows at a later point in time, have a look at following links:

   [how to change the os ubuntu 14.04 to windows completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594681/how-to-change-the-os-ubuntu-14-04-to-windows-completely/594725#594725)

   and

   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)
3. Looking at how concerned you are about not losing Windows 10, you might consider using Ubuntu on Virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the Windows OEM Edition (preinstalled) comes with NO physical backup disk (CD/DVD/USB disk). For anti-piracy reasons. But it comes with a RECOVERY partition on the internal disk, containing all the Windows installation files. You can put those files in an ISO file, like this:

[MS-create bootable ISO from recovery](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-win_upgrade/how-to-create-a-bootable-iso-file-from-your/07590098-90a9-4c7e-b6fe-5ce1632daf4b)

Make sure you have a backup for the Windows Product Key too (write it on paper, in a txt file, whatever). This is important! After you reformat your internal disk, Product Key is unrecoverable.

Make a bootable DVD or USB from the ISO file. Test your bootable medium and make sure it works (it boots up). That's all.